What is seniority in nuclear physics?
The title of this paper is "Lifetime measurement in 94Ru and 93Tc to investigate seniority conservation in the $=50$ isotones".
I do not understand what "seniority" or "seniority conservation" means. It seems that "seniority" has a special meaning in nuclear physics that is different from the usual meaning.

This one's Googleable: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/322/1/012003/pdf page 1.

Another presentation  : https://www.nucleares.unam.mx/lasnpa2024/lasnpa2024_materials/talks/I10_VanIsacker.pdf

I'm tempted to crack a joke about professor titles in academia, but am guessing that attempts at humor are discouraged by the moderators.
